# Finding a product limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

> Evaluate $L=\displaystyle\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(1+\dfrac{1}{a_1}\right) \left(1+\dfrac{1}{a_2}\right) \dots \dots \left(1+\dfrac{1}{a_n }\right)$ where $a_1=1$ and $a_n=n(1+a_{n-1}), \ \forall \ n \geq 2$

By rewriting $L=\displaystyle\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(\dfrac{1+a_1}{a_1}\right) \left(\dfrac{1+a_2}{a_2}\right) \dots \dots \left(\dfrac{1+a_n}{a_n }\right)$ and observing that $1+a_m=\dfrac{a_{m+1}}{m+1}$, I reduced $L$ to $$L=\displaystyle\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$$

I do not know know how to proceed further.

Solutions and hints in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: What I am getting is $a_{n+1}=(n+1)+(n+1)(n)+(n+1)(n)(n-1)+.....+(n+1)!$

Comment: @Aditya Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{(n+1)!}=\frac{1}{n!}+\frac{a_n}{n!}=
\frac{1}{n!}+\frac{1}{(n-1)!}+\frac{a_{n-1}}{(n-1)!}=
\frac{1}{n!}+\frac{1}{(n-1)!}+ \cdots +\frac{1}{2!}+1+1
$$

So 
$$\lim \frac{a_{n+1}}{(n+1)!}=e$$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
   \lim_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{(n+1)!}&= \lim_{n \to\infty}\dfrac{{(n+1)(1+a_n)}}{(n+1)!}\\
     &= \lim_{n \to\infty}(\dfrac{a_n}{n!}+\dfrac{1}{n!})\\
     &= \lim_{n \to\infty}(\dfrac{a_{n-1}}{(n-1)!}+\dfrac{1}{(n-1)!}+\dfrac{1}{n!})\\
      &\vdots\\&= \lim_{n \to\infty}(1+\dfrac{1}{{1}!}+\dfrac{1}{{2}!}+\ldots+\dfrac{1}{n!})\\
       &=e
\end{align}